# "Start ergoemacs command loop" is blocking Emacs

Tags: ergoemacs

I use `ergoemacs` package from MELPA. I've added the following lines from
official manual to my configuration file:

```
(setq ergoemacs-theme nil)
(setq ergoemacs-keyboard-layout "us")
(require 'ergoemacs-mode)
(ergoemacs-mode 1)
```

I can work without problems all day, or every minute see the message

> Start ergoemacs command loop

which blocks Emacs (<kbd>C-g</kbd> has no effect and other keyboard
shortcuts too, the only shortcut that works is
<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>).

- Emacs built from source, version 24.5.1
- OS — Ubuntu 12.04.3
- Desktop environment — Cinnamon

How to fix the problem?

My latest .emacs [here](http://pastebin.com/2AdBpPFt).

Comment: You could try to report the issue via GitHub issue tracker of `ergoemacs-mode`: https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues. If you don't have GitHub account, it's easy to create one. Another benefit of GitHub account is that you will be able to keep your `.emacs` file under version control and share it easily without resorting to pastebin-like services.

Comment: https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/353

Comment: @wasamasa, I haven't studied source code of ergoemacs, but I saw a couple of questions that expose various problems with this package, so my conclusion that some parts of it may consist of low-quality code. See this for example: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/switch-to-next-buffer-under-certain-circumstances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed.

The comments above are asking why ergoemacs-mode reimpliments the command loop.  The bug states what the ergoemacs-mode command loop does.  It also shows how to turn it off.

As far as low-quality code, I'm unsure what @Mark means by that.  However, there are a suite of tests to make sure the functionality is preserved.

EDIT:

I do see the arbitrary nature of the 20 cut-off.  I personally don't use this function and agree this is arbitrary. I have updated the master code base to remove this.  I should probably look at some of the legacy code and make sure it makes sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said I haven't read your code, so I was quite careful when I expressed my opinion: "*some parts* of it *may* consist of low-quality code". Since you admit that "20 cut-off" is far from good coding practice, I was right, in a way. I didn't want to offend you or question your (or other ergoemacs contributors') skills.

Comment: I'm not offended.  I just wish to make it higher quality.